Use Spring Authorization Server as UAA server with a custom provider
I want to create a custom authorization provider for Spring Authorization Server (Something like Google SSO). Is it possible to have a client which communicates with Spring Authorization Server only using API. I don't need a login page.
So far I can't anything useful to solve this problem.

Just to be clear, you want to use an external provider through Spring authorization server right? And what do you mean by "only using API"?

yes for the first question. For the second question I want to sue API keys for authentication. I don't need a login page.

Yes, you can have a client which communicate with Spring Authorization Server it is recommended just for trusted servers, not for public clients.
https://fusionauth.io/articles/oauth/complete-list-oauth-grants
The Client Credentials grant type uses the Id and secret credentials of a Client to authorize and access protected data from a resource owner. This grant type is generally used for machine-to-machine authorization, in which a specific user’s permission to access data isn’t required. It can be used in a cron job that performs daily housekeeping tasks on the server.

Can you add some code example how to implement this?
